# Extract all except in stringr

Tags: stringr

I have a list of the following files

`a_file.csv`
`another_file.csv`
`a_third_file.csv`

I would like to write a function that will `paste` only the text before `_file.csv` so the above strings would be.

`a`
`another`
`a_third`

how can I do this with `stringr`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str_split`:

```
str_split("a_file.csv", "_file.csv")
```

This will return a list of pieces based on the pattern "_file.csv". [Documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/stringr.html)

Answer (score 5):

Just because you explicitly asked, here is a `str_extract_all()` solution. You need to use a so-called “[positive lookahead](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)”.

```r
library(stringr)

x <- c("a_file.csv", "another_file.csv", "a_third_file.csv")

str_extract_all(x, regex(".*(?=_file.csv)"))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a" "" 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "another" ""       
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "a_third" ""
```

@Joel’s answer, i.e. `str_split`, is more concise, of course, and faster as well. I am using `fixed()` here, since we are matching a fixed string, not a regular expression.

```r
str_split(x, fixed("_file.csv"))
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a" "" 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "another" ""       
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "a_third" ""
```

base R or rather the `utils::strsplit()` can do this just as well, of course, but note that the empty strings are gone.

```r
strsplit(x, "_file.csv", fixed = TRUE)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "a"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "another"
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1] "a_third"
```

A single character vector as return value is even more concise, IMO. Three alternatives:

1. `str_extract()` with a positive lookahead.

```r
str_extract(x, regex(".*(?=_file.csv)"))
#> [1] "a"       "another" "a_third"
```

2. Instead of extracting the strings you want, you can also replace/delete the strings you don’t want.

```r
str_replace(x, fixed("_file.csv"), "")
#> [1] "a"       "another" "a_third"
```

3. The same strategy with `base::gsub()`

```r
gsub("_file.csv", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
#> [1] "a"       "another" "a_third"
```